# How to control what divs jQuery slideToggle pushes down

Tags: jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I am new to writing jQuery and have a question related to the slideToggle function. I am developing a page with team members. When you click on their photo I want the photos below to slide down and the content to appear. I have 4 rows with three photos in each on desktop view. For mobile view there are 5 rows with 2 photos in each. In order for the content to show up under the correct photo I put the content directly under the related photo in my HTML. Then I used the slideToggle function to slide the content down when the photo is clicked. Because the content is before the rest of the photos in the row it is pushing everything down, including the photos that should remain next to the photo that is clicked. Is there a way to have the photos at the end of the row remain in their position?

Here is my HTML for one row:

```
        <div class="portfoliowork">
            <img src="images/portfolioph.jpg" class="togglephoto" data-toggleid="toggledesc4">
        </div>
        <div class="toggledesc toggledesc4">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="portfoliowork">
            <img src="images/portfolioph.jpg" class="togglephoto" data-toggleid="toggledesc5">
        </div>
        <div class="toggledesc toggledesc5">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="portfoliowork">
            <img src="images/portfolioph.jpg" class="togglephoto" data-toggleid="toggledesc6">
        </div>
        <div class="toggledesc toggledesc6">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
```

Here is the CSS related to the JQuery:

```
.toggledesc{
    padding:1%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}

.portfoliowork{
    width:33%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding:1%;
 }


@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .portfoliowork{
     width:50%;
   }
}
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
<script>
$('img[data-char=togglephoto1]')
    $(function(){
        $('.toggledesc').hide();

        $('.togglephoto').on('click', function(){
            var toggleid = $(this).attr('data-toggleid');

            $('.' +toggleid).slideToggle("slow");
        });

    });
</script>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for your comment. When the first photo in a row is clicked the description does come down. But it pushes the second and third photos next to it down. I want the entire row to stay in place when the description slides down.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are saying you would like the descriptions to appear one at a time, in which case I would add just one line:

```js
$('img[data-char=togglephoto1]')
    $(function(){
        $('.toggledesc').hide();

        $('.togglephoto').on('click', function(){
            var toggleid = $(this).attr('data-toggleid');
            $('.toggledesc').not('.' +toggleid).slideUp("slow");  // new line
            $('.togglephoto').not('.' +toggleid).css('border','')
            $('.' +toggleid).slideToggle("slow");
            $(this).css('border','solid black 1px');
        });

    });
```

```css
.toggledesc{
    padding:1%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}

img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  }

.portfoliowork {
  display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="portfoliowork">
            <img src="http://infinitelives.net/avatars/mangajen.jpg" class="togglephoto" data-toggleid="toggledesc4">
        </div>
        <div class="portfoliowork">
            <img src="http://www.zdar.net/wp/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/avatar-face-your-manga.jpg" class="togglephoto" data-toggleid="toggledesc5">
        </div>
        <div class="portfoliowork">
            <img src="http://zarkseven.files.wordpress.com/2008/08/avatar.jpg" class="togglephoto" data-toggleid="toggledesc6">
        </div>
        <div class="toggledesc toggledesc4">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="toggledesc toggledesc5">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="toggledesc toggledesc6">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: That is not the issue I wrote about, but it is something else I was still trying to figure out, so thank you! The issue I am having deals with how the second and third photos in the row get pushed down when the first photo is clicked. Then in responsive view it is a two column layout. So the second photo is pushed down when the first one is clicked.

Comment: This works perfectly for desktop view. But I also have a media query (I just added it to the question) that breaks it down to a two column view when on a mobile device. With the code like this, it put the descriptions under all three images, instead of the one it corresponds with.

Answer (score 0):

If you need all three images to remain next to each other, put them all in one DIV, then you can hide all three description DIVs below them. When you click an image, hide the descriptions that don't correspond first (if any are shown), then show the one you want to see (if none are shown, simply show the one corresponding with the image you clicked on). Here's the jQuery:

```
$('.togglephoto').on('click', function(){
    var toggleid = $(this).attr('data-toggleid');
    if($('.toggledesc:visible').size() > 0){
        $('.toggledesc:visible').not('.' + toggleid).slideUp(function(){
            $('.' +toggleid).slideToggle("slow");
        });
    }
    else{
        $('.' +toggleid).slideToggle("slow");
    }
});
```

And the CSS:

```
.toggledesc{
    display:none;
}
```

You can check the Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/14thum65/) to see the HTML - it's a bit long.

Edit: To add a second column, for your mobile version, you can just put the HTML from the above answer in one DIV (we'll give it a class of container), set its width to 50% (or whatever you desire), and set it to float left. Then you can basically copy and paste that entire DIV, change the class numbers of the descriptions within and their corresponding "togglers", and set the second .container to float right. That handles the HTML, now just update the JS to look at only the .toggledesc elements in the same .container as the "toggler" you clicked on, using this:

`$(this).closest('.container').find('.toggledesc:visible')`...

instead of just toggling all visible descriptions.

That's probably not the best way to word all that, but here's a fiddle so you can see what I mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/5a8q0smm/

Comment: I think this is what I had at first. But the site is responsive. In the mobile view there are two columns instead of three. So placing the descriptions below the three images would make them show out of place when in the two column view.

Comment: Updated my answer to, hopefully, account for your mobile needs.